# Run 2 .net WebAPI's

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net application the uses WebAPI to get data from DB.
This application can host extensions through connection points.
One of the extensions uses also WebAPI to get data from DB.
It seems that both of them cant run together.
The extension adds to web.config the following elements:

```
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="ImpersonationWebApiConfig"/>
        <add name="ImpersonationWebApiConfig" type="Impersonation.Application.WebApi.App_Start.WebApiConfig"   preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
```

When i delete/Change the additional elements on the web.config the main works and the extension WebAPI gets 404 error. When the new elements exist on the Web.config the main app (the host) returns 404 erros message for every WebAPI call.

please advise

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the extension contained RouteTable.Routes.Clear() in the WebApiConfig file. This method cleans the Route Table that contained routes from the application and the extension.